# Small jQuery to update cart stopped working (Woocommerce/Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a small script so the cart would update itself after I changed the value and clicked outside the input-field. But now it stopped working and I have no idea why :/

1. You need to put something in the cart (press: "In den Warenkorb"): http://vamedics.com/de/shop/2-lendenwirbel/
2. Now at the cart just change the number in the input field and it should refresh the site but it doesn't change the price nor the quantity: http://vamedics.com/de/warenkorb/

It may not be the best jquery in the world but it did its job :/ It would just press the refresh cart button (it's hidden via display: none) and refresh everything while updating the cart

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input-qty').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
    elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
      if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

        $("#input-qty").focusout(function() {
          $('input[type="submit"]:nth-child(2)').trigger('click');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The code refreshes the page, I think the problem could be the server side code not bringing back the correct values possibly.

Comment: I'm with @Dane. It refreshes the page an sends the updated amount as `qty=` to the server. It just isn't updated correctly on the server.

Comment: Oh wait. I see why. You're sending the old value aswell. The post concists of two `qty=`. The first one is the new value and the second one is the old value. Which results in the server placing the old value as `qty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hidden mobile version of the cart which contains the quantity aswell. When you update the page by sending the form you're sending duplicate names for everything. The cart and the quantity.

This was my request when I changed the quantity:

`cart%5B9dd3ecb6819c19341cce4399afa2c7dd%5D%5Bqty%5D=1&cart%5B9dd3ecb6819c19341cce4399afa2c7dd%5D%5Bqty%5D=10&coupon_code=&update_cart=Warenkorb+aktualisieren&_wpnonce=b5b38505ed&_wp_http_referer=%2Fde%2Fwarenkorb%2F`

You can see that the cart and its quantity is specified twice. Once with the old value and once with the new value.

Either make a separate form when you're submitting through JS or make sure you're changing both quantities.

Comment: Ahhh true! I added the mobile cart yesterday and before that the quantity change worked. I will try to modify the JS/make a sperate form. Thank you!

Do you know why it wouldn't work on anything than the 1st item? If I add a 2nd it just doesn't work

Comment: I would guess it's because you're using `#` as a selector - it's meant to get a single element. If you would change the selector to `.` instead it would probably work.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer. :)